# Should I set PYTHONPATH for the pre-install python on MacOS 13 M1/M2?

Tags: command-line, python

On the new MacOS 13 M1/M2, python 3.9 is pre-installed with pip3 (no pip). I don't install other Python versions with brew/macport or Python installer, only the pre-install 3.9.

With the pre-install python, the global site-package is located in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (other installers will be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/`)

The per-user site-package is located in `~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`

When I pip3 install a package, it will be installed to the per-user location, not the global location, along with the executable files installed `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin`. For example, after I upgrade pip3, pip will also be installed in `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin`.

I want to **run these executable files installed by pip3 without specifying the full path**. When I upgraded pip3 the system still complained it couldn't find pip, and it took me some time to figure out why.

I can add `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to PATH directly but I feel it is an ad hoc solution. For example, with the next macOS release, the pre-installed Python may upgrade to 3.10 (as that happened before) I may need to add `~/Library/Python/3.10/bin` to PATH too. I have seen from time to time that `PATH` is modified to be **long and ugly** just to include Python and the related executable files.

Should I set `PYTHONPATH` to `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin` and add PYTHONPATH to PATH? I would like to know what is the best practice for using `PYTHONPATH/PYTHONHOME` for the pre-install python on Mac.

Both `PYTHONPATH/PYTHONHOME` are not set by default.

From [What exactly should be set in PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath), the agreed-upon answers are that I don't need to set PYTHONPATH unless there are non-standard libraries I want to use. But these answers seem not to solve my problem, of course, I need to use non-standard libraries for my development, say pytorch.

--- update ---

From the comments I got, I realized I installed python3 with  `xcode-select --install`, MacOS 13 doesn't preinstall python3.

Also from the comments let me reiterate my questions, 1. Should I set `PYTHONPATH/PYTHONHOME`, why or why not? 2. I feel adding `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to PATH is an ad hoc solution and I would like to know if is there a better way.

Of course, I need to add those executables' paths to the PATH in the end. But I didn't know the correct usage of PYTHONPATH so I thought maybe I could add those executables' paths to PYTHONPATH and then add PYTHONPATH to PATH. In that way when I have more paths to add, I just need to edit PYTHONPATH and PATH remains the same.

But that seems not to be the proper usage of PYTHONPATH from what I have so far.

Comment: Please explain the exact issue you are having. macOS does not include python3 so how did you install it (Xcode does include it) From Xcode pip3 is on the PATH. What application are you tryingn to install

Comment: As I said in my question "My goal is to run these executable files installed by pip3 without specifying the full path.", e.g. `pip install python-dotenv` will install `dotenv` in `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin`

Comment: @mmmmmm I updated my question according to your comment.

Comment: FWIW I am not sure how much it matches your concerns but a lot of “advanced” `pip` users seem to recommend `python -m pip install python-dotenv` to avoid the pip being outta sync w the python.  I’ve mostly configured pip, somehow, now, so it’s not worth doing for me. But I encountered glitches that python -m pip would have avoided.  I would also **avoid** messing w a system macos python, install your own python.org download or macports.  Homebrew installs can auto-update python versions, supposedly which can cause issues.

Comment: @JLPeyret thanks for the comment but I have yet to find a way to set my path. Of course I can just add `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to my path, but that kinda defeat the purpose of me asking this long question.

Comment: I am really unclear what your concern is.  Is it that, when you run the system python, it can't *import* what you've installed, in python scripts?  Is it that you can't run python-based utilities like `black` on the macos command line directly?  Is it that when you run "something"  *as another user* Python can't import packages in *your* `~/Library/...`? Is because you want other Xcode components to use it?  Without knowing this, your insistence on messing with `PYTHONPATH`, contrary to the given answer, makes no sense whatsoever to me, as a fairly advanced Python user on macos.

Comment: Now, one thing you can look is using `.pth` files.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209116/1394353 You may also want to run, and post the contents of, `python -m site` output in your question.

Comment: Just ignore PYTHONPATH until something breaks which it is very unlikely to do - if you say you have non-standard libraries which exact ones are they.

Comment: I do python development so I definitely will use non-standard libraries, numpy, pytorch, python-dotenv, watchdog, uvicorn (just name a few). python-dotenv watchdog, uvicorn all install with executables.

Answer (score 3):

Leave `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` alone.

Add the `bin` directory containing the executables you want to run to your path.

Comment: Why leave PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH alone?

Comment: I check many articles about setting the path right for python, but I didn't any of them say adding `~/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to path. Of course, I can just do that. But I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: It is the simplest and only way for the executables otherwise the shell can't find them. Python is setup so that the PYTHON* variables just work.

Comment: If you are just running python3 then that is on the PATH and you do not need anything else.

Comment: @mmmmmm Well, depending on where you get the `python` from.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Do you think there's some other way for the shell to find an executable?

Comment: @MarcWilson Whichpythons > 3.9 does not get installed on the PATH by itself or the packamanager that you use?

Comment: @mmmmmm If you build if yourself, who knows?  If you use MacPorts, it will.  If you use python.org, I have no idea.

Comment: python.org goes into /usr/local/bin as does a self build unless you change where it installs - anywhay the OP is where do pip installed python apps end up

Comment: Of course, I need to add those executables' path to the PATH in the end. I didn't know the correct usage of PYTHONPATH before I asked the question, so I thought maybe I could add executables' paths to PYTHONPATH and then add PYTHONPATH to PATH. In that way when I have more paths to add, I just need to  edit PYTHONPATH, PATH remains the same. But you guys all said leave PYTHONPATH alone.

Comment: Yes you get it - python knows where its internal paths are but the shell you run from does not klnow where pip installs executables.